# How to set variables from each line store in file

Tags: bash

I want to read a file line by line and pass the first and second fields as arguments to a bash script, then iterate to the next line and do the same thing.

My file is pwd.out:

```
/path/dir/name1/date name1
/path/dir/name2/date name2
```

I have tried the following without success:

```
while read line; do dir=`awk '{print $1}'`; name=`awk '{print $2}'`; echo "./myprogram $dir somethingHere $name"; done < pwd.out
```

where it outputs:

```
./myprogram /path/dir/name1/date /path/dir/name2/date somethingHere
```

I think that somehow $dir is getting the values from all the lines and $name is not being set.

What I would like to have is:

```
./myprogram /path/dir/name1/date somethingHere name1
./myprogram /path/dir/name2/date somethingHere name2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need awk for this. Just `read` the variables in the order they come, such as this:

```
while read dir name
do
   ./myprogram $dir somethingHere $name
done < pwd.out
```

#### Test

See an example in which I just echo `dir=$dir, name=$name` with your given file:

```
$ while read dir name; do echo "dir=$dir, name=$name"; done < pwd.out
dir=/path/dir/name1/date, name=name1
dir=/path/dir/name2/date, name=name2
```

---

Your `awk` command was not working because you were not giving any input to it.

It could work if you did this, although it is unnecessary to use an external command like `awk` with something that bash can handle perfectly as you can see above.

```
while read line
do
   dir=$(awk '{print $1}' <<< "$line")
   name=$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "$line")
   echo "./myprogram $dir somethingHere $name"
done < pwd.out
```

Comment: great. The simpler, the better.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read dir name; do
    echo "dir=$dir name=$name"
done < pwd.out
```

Comment: Honestly I don't see the point of this answer. It came later than mine, using the same logic and without any explanation.

Comment: @fedorqui When I made my answer your answer wasn't visible to me.